# limit number of rows with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to display up to 4 rows in a table with `ng-repeat`.  If there are more than 4 rows I want a plus sign to appear on the 5th row which, when clicked, will reveal the rest of the rows in the dataset.  I'm not really sure where to start.

```
table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
  thead
    tr
      th.spacer.col-md-8
        | Products: {{co.products.length}} Total - Click to preview
      th.col-md-2
        span.qty-ordered Qty Ordered
      th.col-md-2
        span.co-price Price
  tbody
    tr ng-repeat="prod in co.products"
        td.co-product-name.col-md-6
          a () {{prod.name}}
        td.col-md-3
          span () XX
        td.col-md-3
          span () {{prod.prices[0].price | currency}}
```

Comment: The question for u is, Do u want to hide/show the rows on click or Dynamically add the rows on click ??

Comment: just hide/show, not dynamically add.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use limit filter:

```
tr ng-repeat="prod in co.products | limitTo : limit"
    td.co-product-name.col-md-6
      a () {{prod.name}}
    td.col-md-3
      span () XX
    td.col-md-3
      span () {{prod.prices[0].price | currency}}
tr ng-show='limit' ng-click='limit = undefined'



# controller

$scope.limit = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a ng-if, something like this:

```
table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
  thead
    tr
      th.spacer.col-md-8
        | Products: {{co.products.length}} Total - Click to preview
      th.col-md-2
        span.qty-ordered Qty Ordered
      th.col-md-2
        span.co-price Price

  tbody ng-if="expanded"
    tr ng-repeat="prod in co.products"
        td.co-product-name.col-md-6
          a () {{prod.name}}
        td.col-md-3
          span () XX
        td.col-md-3
          span () {{prod.prices[0].price | currency}}

  tbody ng-if="!expanded"
    tr ng-repeat="prod in co.products.slice(0,4)"
        td.co-product-name.col-md-6
          a () {{prod.name}}
        td.col-md-3
          span () XX
        td.col-md-3
          span () {{prod.prices[0].price | currency}}
    tr ng-click="expanded = true" show me more...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$index` property provided.

logic would be in controller and template.

in controller:

```
$scope.notPlus = true;
```

in template:

```
tr ng-repeat="prod in co.products" ng-if={{ notPlus and $index < 4}}
```

and further below a link that will flip the noPlus value to false

```
a ng-click={{notPlus = !notPlus}}
```

This will fulfill the DRY principle and make your code more manageable

```
table.table.table-striped.table-bordered
  thead
    tr
      th.spacer.col-md-8
        | Products: {{co.products.length}} Total - a ng-click={{notPlus = !notPlus}} Click to preview
      th.col-md-2
        span.qty-ordered Qty Ordered
      th.col-md-2
        span.co-price Price
  tbody
    tr ng-repeat="prod in co.products" ng-if={{ notPlus and $index < 4}}
        td.co-product-name.col-md-6
          a () {{prod.name}}
        td.col-md-3
          span () XX
        td.col-md-3
          span () {{prod.prices[0].price | currency}}
```